# Restarle 3 dias a fechas de sql con c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008

```
    public List<DateTime> fechas3()
    {
        List<DateTime> list = new List<DateTime>();
        List<DateTime> fec = new List<DateTime>();
        SqlConnection cone = new SqlConnection(connect);
        cone.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT DispositionDueDate FROM fechas", cone);
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            fec.Add(Convert.ToDateTime(reader[0]));
        }
        return fec;
    }
```

EL codigo anterior me imprime fechas pero yo quisiera restarle tres dias a cada una de esas fechas y mostrarlas en pantalla con esos tres dias menos.
    Ej:

```
  antes               despues 
 20/5/16   ======>>   17/5/16
 15/12/16  ======>>    12/12/16
```

Comment: fue un error que no he podido eliminar.

Comment: No puedes abrir un duplicado de otra pregunta sólo porque te la hayan puesto en espera. Para que se te pueda responder tiene que reabrirse. Eso lo conseguirás haciendo caso de la ayuda, de los comentarios que te han puesto, añadiendo información necesaria. etc... en tu pregunta original, pero no creando un duplicado.

Comment: no he creado duplicado..

Comment: Puedes borrar esta pregunta. De hecho yo ya había editado tu pregunta anterior y votado para que se reabra, pero respeta las normas por favor. Borra esta pregunta.

Answer (score 2):

Podrias restar la fecha directo en el sql

```
string query = "SELECT DATEADD(day,-3, DispositionDueDate) as DispositionDueDate FROM fechas";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cone);
```

como veras con el DATEADD() en la misma query puedes restarle dias

Answer (score 1):

Puedes

```
while (reader.Read())
{
   DateTime fecha = Convert.ToDateTime(reader[0]);
   fecha = fecha.AddDays(-3);
   fec.Add(fecha);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba utilizando el método AddDays de DateTime. En tu ejemplo:

```
fec.Add(Convert.ToDateTime(reader[0]).AddDays(-3));
```